# Find an SDE given a probability density function p(x,t)

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

Usually, we start with an SDE for $X(t)$ and then try to solve it and find the corresponding probability density function $p(x,t)$. But what if we start with a pdf - can we find a corresponding SDE? How can this be done? Would we use the Fokker-Plank equation and try to "guess" the mean and diffusion coefficient? Or is there an approach that doesn't require guessing? Would such SDE be unique?

Comment: If you have the Fokker-Plank equation you don't need to 'guess' the cofficients, you can read them off.

Comment: @Tobsn Thank you for your comment. Yes, clearly if the FP equation is already available than we can just read them off. However, what I meant by "using the FP" is to take the derivatives of the pdf (which is assumed to be the only "thing" available to us) and try to "construct" the FP.

Comment: From the density kernel you can determine the generator of the diffusion from which you can read of FPeq and the SDE, respectively.

Comment: @Tobsn  And how does one "determine the generator of the diffusion"? And, for that matter, what is meant by "the generator of the diffusion"? Thank you

Comment: $\mathcal{A}f(x)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{t}\left(\int f(y)p_{t}(x,dy)-f(x)\right)$. What the generator $\mathcal{A}$ is/does you'll find in the literature.

Comment: @Tobsn And what is the function $f(x)$ in your formula?